# Is number after DateTime2 is for nanosecond purpose?

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime2

I have read the document already but i do not fully understand
The default precision is datetime2(7) is 7 represent the precision of nanosecond?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The resolution of the default precision (7) for the `datetime2` type is 100 nanoseconds.

An excellent reference for things date/time is: [The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes).

Answer (score 12):

No, the number represents the number of digits preserved after the decimal point for the seconds. 3 would be millisecond, 6 microsecond and 7 equivalent to a precision of 100 nanoseconds.